# How to add properties from a root object in a nested object for sorting?

Tags: elasticsearch

A simplified example of the kind of document in our index:

```
{ 
  "organisation" : { 
    "code" : "01310"
  },
  "publications" : [ 
    { 
      "dateEnd" : 1393801200000,
      "dateStart" : 1391986800000,
      "code" : "PUB.02"
    },
    { 
      "dateEnd" : 1401055200000,
      "dateStart" : 1397512800000,
      "code" : "PUB.06"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that `publications` are mapped as `nested` objects because we need to filter based on a combination of the `dateEnd`, `dateStart` and `publicationStatus` properties.

The `PUB.02` status code is special. It states: 'this publication period is valid if the current user is a member of the organisation'.

I have a problem when I want to sort on 'most recent':

```
{
  "sort": {
    "publications.dateStart" : {
      "mode" :  "min",
      "order" : "desc",
      "nested_filter" : {
        "or" : [
          {
            "and" : [
              { "term" : { "organisation.code" : "01310" } },
              { "term" : { "publications.code" : "PUB.02" } }
            ]
          },
          { "term" : { "publications.code" : "PUB.06" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No error is given, but the `PUB.02` entry is ignored. I tried to use `copy_to` in my mapping to copy the value of `organisation.code` to the `nested` object, but that did not help.

- Is there a way to reach for the parent document inside a nested sort?
- Alternatively, is there a way to copy data from parent to the nested document?

I am currently using version 1.7 of Elasticsearch without the ability to use scripts. Upgrading to a newer version could be done if that would help the situation.

This gist shows that the sort is performed on the `PUB.06` publications: https://gist.github.com/EECOLOR/2db9a1ec9d6d5c791ea6

Comment: Can you give an example of failure? I tested this and it's giving weird results if I don't use the same filter from `sort` in the query itself.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have added [a gist](https://gist.github.com/EECOLOR/2db9a1ec9d6d5c791ea6) showing the problem

Comment: With the two documents you've given in your gist, what is the result you're expecting? I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve in your `sort` clause.

Comment: @Val That the `sort` value for `a` is `1` and for `b` it's `2`

Comment: The thing is that the second `term` on `PUB.06` matches both of your documents, just remember that you're sorting the top-level documents, not the nested objects.

Comment: @Val I know, that's why I use `"mode": "min"`

Comment: @EECOLOR Basically, you want to sort on a value belonging to the nested object that matched the query only.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I am not sure I would use those words. But `nested_filter` in a `sort` selects the documents that should be included in the `sort`. In my case I want to filter based on properties from the root document as well as the nested document. It seems however that nested documents can not 'reach out', so I try to use `copy_to` to get the value inside the nested document.

Answer (score 1):

Although the documentation does not explictly mention it does look like we cannot access the parent field in a nested filter context.

Also I wasn't able to use `copy_to` to add data from root/parent field to nested document. I would suggest asking in [elasticsearch discuss thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/) you would have more luck about the reasons for this.

Before some trigger happy bloke downvotes this answer I would like to add that the query and intended results that was  desired in the OP using `sort` could be achieved using [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) work-around.

One implementation to achieve this is as follows

1) start of with a should query

2) In the first should clause

```
 a) use filtered query  to filter documents with the `organisation.code : 01310`

  b) then score these documents  based on max value of reciprocal of nested document **dateStart** with terms **PUB2.0 PUB6.0**
```

3) In the second should clause

```
 a) use filtered query  to filter documents with those with `organisation.code not equal to  01310`

  b) like before score these documents  based on max value of reciprocal of  nested document **dateStart** with term **PUB6.0** only
```

Example Query:

```
POST /testindex/testtype/_search 
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "filtered": {
                  "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "organisation.code": "01310"
                     }
                  },
                  "query": {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "publications",
                        "query": {
                           "filtered": {
                              "query": {
                                 "function_score": {
                                    "functions": [
                                       {
                                          "field_value_factor": {
                                             "field": "publications.dateStart",
                                             "modifier": "reciprocal"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ],
                                    "boost_mode": "replace",
                                    "score_mode": "max"
                                 }
                              },
                              "filter": {
                                 "terms": {
                                    "publications.code": [
                                       "PUB.02",
                                       "PUB.06"
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "max"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "filtered": {
                  "filter": {
                     "not": {
                        "term": {
                           "organisation.code": "01310"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "query": {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "publications",
                        "query": {
                           "filtered": {
                              "query": {
                                 "function_score": {
                                    "functions": [
                                       {
                                          "field_value_factor": {
                                             "field": "publications.dateStart",
                                             "modifier": "reciprocal"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ],
                                    "boost_mode": "replace",
                                    "score_mode": "max"
                                 }
                              },
                              "filter": {
                                 "terms": {
                                    "publications.code": [
                                       "PUB.06"
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "max"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I'm first to admit it is not the most readable and if there is a way to 'copy_to' nested it would be much more ideal

If not simulating `copy_to` by injecting data in the source by client before indexing would be more simpler and flexible.

But the above is an example of how it could be done using function scores.

Comment: What the OP is asking is not doable imo using his initial approach. function_score approach is a good workaround. +1